# How to keep all folders collapsed when opening VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open my workspace in VS Code, I see all my folders as expanded and I have to collapse them manually. I want VS Code to keep all the folders in my workspace as collapsed when I open it, so that I don't have to do that manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Visual Studio Code from expanding all the folders in my workspace on launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808451/how-to-stop-visual-studio-code-from-expanding-all-the-folders-in-my-workspace-on)

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of these shortcut keys if you want the same,

```
Ctrl+Shift+[    Fold (collapse) region  editor.fold
Ctrl+Shift+]    Unfold (uncollapse) region  editor.unfold
Ctrl+K Ctrl+[   Fold (collapse) all subregions  editor.foldRecursively
Ctrl+K Ctrl+]   Unfold (uncollapse) all subregions  editor.unfoldRecursively
Ctrl+K Ctrl+0   Fold (collapse) all regions editor.foldAll
Ctrl+K Ctrl+J   Unfold (uncollapse) all regions
```