# How to stop Visual Studio Code from expanding all the folders in my workspace on launch?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I launch Visual Studio Code, it will automatically expand/unfold all the root folders in my workspace. It didn't use to do that.

What can I do to find my workspace in the same state it was when I closed the editor? I've tried numerous settings and reinstalled the editor completly (removing all preferences and data) but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, it is this fixed issue:

[As of 1.61, re-opening a workspace doesn't remember folder collapse states](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134665)

The next release v1.62 should be out this week.  You could test it in the Insiders Build.

Comment: Thanks, it is the same issue indeed. Hopefully this version will solve it.

Comment: Just installed the the v1.62-insider and the issue seems fixed.